# SnakeYaml: escaping new line characters in yaml

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I've just tried the following code snippet in a groovy console

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
o = new Yaml().load("a: a\\nb")
o.a
```

and it returns

```
a\nb
```

instead of

```
a
b
```

I've followed [this](http://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-05-15.html) guide

I was wondering if it's a bug, or I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it out

To be escaped, the value has to be between double quotes, like this:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
o = new Yaml().load('a: "a\\nb"')
o.a
```

output:

```
groovy> import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml 
groovy> o = new Yaml().load('a: "a\\nb"') 
groovy> o.a 

Result: a
b
```